# How to minimize this Comparator method using java 8

Tags: java, comparator

How to minimize this Comparator method using java 8
Actually I pass List of WorkingDays  that contains List of Days I need to sort dates in ascending and descending order how it possible
I need date in ascending order

```
private List<WorkingDays> workingDaysDateSortDesc(List<WorkingDays> workingDays) {
    Collections.sort(workingDays.get(0).getDays(), new Comparator<Days>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Days o1, Days o2) {
            if (o1.getDate().get$date() == null || o2.getDate().get$date() == null)
                return 0;
            return o2.getDate().get$date().compareTo(o1.getDate().get$date());
        }
    });
    return workingDays;
}
```

Comment: Please use **stream API**, it will give you advantages and make code more cleaner and more readable.

Comment: It's unclear what result you want with regards to `null` values. Can you post a sample input / output? What do you mean by minimize anyway?

Comment: @Tunaki I need date in acending order.

Comment: @Zin Min Can you help me to write this code in stream way

Comment: Dates in ascending order don't tell anything for what should happen with `null` values. Your current comparator is saying any `null` date is equal to any date, `null` or not.

Comment: @AraviS I can give you simple example -> The following code line is for sorting string list by it's length. **sList.stream().sorted((s1,s2) -> {return s2.length() - s1.length();}).forEach(System.out::println);**

Answer (score 0):

Just use lambda:

```
private List<WorkingDays> workingDaysDateSortDesc(List<WorkingDays> workingDays) {
    Collections.sort(workingDays.get(0).getDays(), (Comparator<Days>) (o1, o2) -> {
        if (o1.getDate().get$date() == null || o2.getDate().get$date() == null)
            return 0;
        return o2.getDate().get$date().compareTo(o1.getDate().get$date());
    });
    return workingDays;
}
```